# How can I click to close pop up windows when entering a website with selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I need to click on the button "Got it" on the pop-up that opens when I enter the website https://it.investing.com/ (then I also need to close other two windows but I guess understanding how to handle one is fine).

This is my code and the last line is supposed to click on the button, navigating to it by using its XPATH that I extracted from the HTML of the page through the "copy XPATH" option. Still, it doesn't happen and the webdriver just runs out of time.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()            #Chromedriver must be in the same folder 
driver.get('https://it.investing.com/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]"))).click()
```

This is where it stops:

[image: popup]

Comment: I don't find any "Got it" button as such. Can you provide some more details which element you are trying to click?

Comment: I just posted the link to the image of where it stops.

Comment: The popup you mentioned doesn't appears just by accessing the url `https://it.investing.com/` but I do observe the popup behind the mentioned popup

Comment: I'm really just guessing but maybe it does if you run the code. Anyway are you able to close the pop up you see using python? Otherwise can you think of any other solution to this?